# Search Gerrit for commits previously rejected by a reviewer

Tags: gerrit

### Question

How do you search for commits which have ever received CodeReview-2 in the past from a given reviewer?

### Context

Basically I want to do a retrospective on every commits I've ever rejected so that I can share those the comments to more people.
It's very easy to get the commits I'm currently rejecting using the search terms `reviewer:self label:CodeReview-2`.

But once the owner of the commit fixes the issue with a new patchset and I put a +2 on it, I won't be able to search for that commit anymore.

So I'm looking for something like `had-label:CodeReview-2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At our local installation we get an email from gerrit at each scoring.

Thus, as a workaround, you can search for emails from gerrit containing "< your login > has posted comments on this change." and "Code-Review-2".